# Nginx 403 Forbidden when running PHP

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-403

Note: **I didn't Get my answear anywhere That's why I'm making this**

My nginx.conf file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
           root           html;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

I also ran

```
php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

in my command prompt in my C:\PHP

**The error i get is**

> 403 Forbidden
> nginx/1.19.7

in Localhost.

I don't have a proxy on and I really don't know what the error is
***I noticed that There was a Error file***
So here are the contents of that file :

```
2021/03/08 07:13:46 [emerg] 17544#7752: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)
2021/03/08 07:14:04 [emerg] 1160#19796: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)
2021/03/08 07:14:15 [emerg] 15840#20192: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)
2021/03/08 07:17:55 [error] 17248#19796: *9 CreateFile() "C:\nginx/html/robots.txt" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /robots.txt?448659 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:25:13 [error] 17248#19796: *41 CreateFile() "C:\nginx/html/phpmyadmin" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:26:02 [error] 17248#19796: *41 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/Facebook/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /Facebook/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:26:07 [error] 17248#19796: *48 CreateFile() "C:\nginx/html/robots.txt" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /robots.txt?448659 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:26:48 [error] 17248#19796: *49 CreateFile() "C:\nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
2021/03/08 07:26:53 [error] 17248#19796: *49 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/Facebook/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /Facebook/ HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2021/03/08 07:31:00 [error] 17248#19796: *70 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:31:00 [error] 17248#19796: *70 CreateFile() "C:\nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
2021/03/08 07:31:42 [error] 17248#19796: *70 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:31:43 [error] 17248#19796: *70 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:31:43 [error] 17248#19796: *70 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:32:24 [error] 17248#19796: *70 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:32:27 [error] 17248#19796: *70 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:32:28 [error] 17248#19796: *70 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:32:28 [error] 17248#19796: *70 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:32:29 [error] 17248#19796: *70 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:34:07 [error] 17248#19796: *89 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:35:52 [error] 17248#19796: *94 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:35:52 [error] 17248#19796: *94 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:35:53 [error] 17248#19796: *94 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:35:53 [error] 17248#19796: *94 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:35:53 [error] 17248#19796: *94 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:35:54 [error] 17248#19796: *94 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:37:29 [error] 17248#19796: *111 directory index of "C:\nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2021/03/08 07:37:29 [error] 17248#19796: *111 CreateFile() "C:\nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```

Comment: What files are in the `C:\nginx/html/` directory?

Comment: @RichardSmith I have a index.html file which works and a Folder called Script which has my PHP code in it

Comment: Have you tried to open `http://localhost/index.php` ? Is your `index.php` script inside `c:\nginx\html` ?

Comment: Yes, I have even tried 127.0.0.1:900/index.php, for the second question Yes

Comment: First of all it looks like you can not even bind on Port 80. Are you able to see your index.html file in your browser on `localhost`? The reason for your 403 is like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941065/after-setting-up-server-blocks-nginx-is-not-serving-my-domain-name/66943827?noredirect=1#comment118333330_66943827. There is something wrong with your root location or the index.html. Please share a screenshot of ` C:\nginx\html`

Comment: @TimoStark I reinstalled Nginx and did some new configurations and its now fixed ! My issue was 1. I didnt reload nginx 2. The video i was watching to setup nginx configured nginx in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
Faced similar issue. Run the above command in command prompt.
This should free up port 80, and you'd be able to run nginx.

Description:
netsh http commands are used to query and configure HTTP.sys settings and parameters.

add iplisten : Adds a new IP address to the IP listen list, excluding the port number.
"::" means any IPv6 address.

For more netsh http commands refer the netsh http commands documentation.

### after making the settings restart NGiNx

And refresh the page in different browsers

```
service nginx restart
```

OR

```
service nginx stop

service nginx start
```

**Check the status of NGINX**

```
service nginx status
```

if the problem continues, make a full backup of the project.

uninstall the NGINX server

```
  apt remove nginx

   apt autoremove

   apt install nginx
```

when removing the server make sure that only the server is being uninstalled.
so you don't have problems with other Server add-ons.

***study about***

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Sadly this didn't hlep! The problem was with my nginx.conf file!