# After setting up server blocks, Nginx is not serving my domain name

Tags: nginx, webserver, web-deployment, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am in the process of deploying my MERN app to a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 20.04 server).

I followed the steps in the following tutorial to install Nginx. [I have completed all the previous steps]

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04

When I visit `http://134.122.112.22`, I see the Nginx landing page, as expected.
[image]

However, after setting up server blocks, when I visit `http://sundaray.io`, I get the following error.
[image]

`sundaray.io` is my domain name.

When I run the command `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, I see the following:
[image]

How can I fix the error?

**EDIT-1**

**SERVER BLOCK**
In order to create the server block, I executed the following commands in order:

1. `mkdir -p /var/www/sundaray.io/html`
2. `nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/sundaray.io`
   Then, I pasted in the following configuration block.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/sundaray.io/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name sundaray.io www.sundaray.io;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

**ERROR**
Executing the command `cat /var/log/nginx/error.log` gave me the following result:

[image]

**EDIT-2**

Executing `chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/sundaray.io/html` threw the following error:
[image]

**EDIT-3**

Executing `ps -elf |grep nginx` gave the following result:

[image]

**EDIT-4**
When I executed the command `ls /var/www/sundaray.io/html`, I got the following result:
[image]

Comment: `/var/log/nginx/error.log` is not a command, it's a text file containing all the errors of your server. You can see the content of this file by using less, tail, or cat command. In order to debug, you should provide the nginx config file.

Comment: run command `cat /var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: share server block details

Comment: @HarshManvar I have added the details in the question edit-1.

Comment: @HKS Nginx is not able to get your file system permission. Change file system permission ‘chmod 777 /var/www/sundaray.io/html‘

Comment: @HarshManvar I executed the command `chmod 777 /var/www/sundaray.io/html`. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: The tutorial mentions that you first go through the initial server setup, did you go through it? did you create a new user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. `chmod 777` is NEVER a good idea.

NGINX operats under a runuser. How to check the runuser:

`ps -elf |grep nginx`. Normaly it will be `nginx`. Instead of `777` (Open for everyone) do `chmod -R 755 /path/to/folder` and `chown -R nginx:nginx /path/to/folder`

But agree. For troubleshooting it can be used. But back to your problem.

### 2. Directory-Listing disabled.

The error is telling you nginx can not list the directory content. Which is the default behavior. Make sure

```
root /var/www/sundaray.io/html;
```

This path exists AND

```
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
```

there are one of these files located!

Without any of these files NGINX can't load the default index file on `/`. Put something in `/var/www/sundaray.io/html` like

`printf "<html>\n<body>\n<h1>Hello from NGINX</h1>\n</body>\n</html>" > /var/www/sundaray.io/html/index.html && chown nginx:nginx /var/www/sundaray.io/html/index.html`. This should generate an index.html for you.

If you just want to test your server configuration without any files:

```
location / {
  return 200 "Hello on $host$uri\n";
}
```

Comment: There is a lot to digest here. [I have never deployed to a digital ocean droplet before]. So, If I understand correctly, now I have to execute these two comands: `chmod -R 755 /var/www/sundaray.io/html` & `chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/sundaray.io/html`. Am I right?

Comment: yes - if nginx is your runuser of the nginx worker processes. Thats the default behavior. Do this and you have to have a least a index.html file in your configured webroot. `printf "<html>\n<body>\n<h1>Hello from NGINX</h1>\n</body>\n</html>" > /var/www/sundaray.io/html/index.html && chown nginx:nginx /var/www/sundaray.io/html/index.html` will do it

Comment: running NGINX in DO isn't different from running it on your local Linux VM. So you will be good to test it locally if you want to that first.

Comment: I got an error when executing the command `chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/sundaray.io/html`. Please see EDIT-2 in the question.

Comment: @hks try: chown -R root:root /var/www/sundayray.io/html

Comment: What the runuser of nginx. `ps -elf | grep nginx`

Comment: @TimoStark Please see Edit-3 in the question.

Comment: Please @Tony do not tell a beginner using `root` as a runuser for NGINX workers and set `root` as a owner of files in userspace. This should never be configured like that. If there is not run user at all, and nginx operates fully as root then we should add a runuser and reconfigure nginx probably.

Comment: So your runuser is `www-data`. Good. Use this instead of nginx in the `chown` commands. And try it again.

Comment: I executed `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/sundaray.io/html`. There was no error. Then when I visited `http://sundaray.io`, I got an error message: `403 Forbidden`.

Comment: whats inside your webroot directory: `ls /var/www/sundaray.io/html`

Comment: @TimoStark, well yes you are correct. Note that the tutorial mentions in the beginning that first you need to go through the Initial Server Setup tutorial which includes creating a new user in the system. Did you follow that @hks?

Comment: @TimoStark Please see edit-4. Note: I run my server using the command `pm2 server/index.html`. I have already cloned my GitHub repo.

Comment: Okay... 1st. PLEASE add a index.html file to `/var/www/sundaray.io/html`. You can use `vim` or just copy it over from some where else. OR use `printf "<html>\n<body>\n<h1>Hello from NGINX</h1>\n</body>\n</html>" > /var/www/sundaray.io/html/index.html && chown www-data:www-data /var/www/sundaray.io/html/index.html`

Comment: 2. Please read the NGINX documentation. You configured `root` and `index` but it looks like you haven't understand what the two directives are dooing. `index` Defines files that will be used as an index. The file name can contain variables. Files are checked in the specified order. The last element of the list can be a file with an absolute path. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index

Comment: If you want subscribe my youtube channel to learn more about all things nginx: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjwfVYn2VvAzBWExMb_NaSQ. There is a prety interesting video about how to read NGINX Documentation. That would be a good start for you I guess.

Comment: Thanks Timo. I will take a look.

Comment: Is it working now? I really wanna see a index.html showing up on your domain before calling it a day!

Comment: Ya, I got `Hello from NGINX`.

Comment: @TimoStark Can you please explain in simple terms what have I done wrong and What do I need to do now? I will be really grateful. I have been struggling with this for the last 3 days.

Comment: Huuurrayyyyy!!! You got it! Long story. You have to make sure you upload all your website files into your webroot directory as mentioned in my answer. btw can you mark my post as answer. that would be great. Let me know on youtube or discord if you any further questions.

Comment: Will make a youtube video about this use case and upload to my channel. sure thing.

Comment: Thanks. Will wait for your video.

Comment: @TimoStark Can you please take a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66967621/9409877

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I was returning https but hadn't set up my encryption certificates.

I set the up with certbot and now they work. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04