# Unable to fix NGINX 502: Bad Gateway error on a Digital Ocean droplet - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, nginx, web-deployment, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have deployed my website to a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 20.04 server).

Everything was working fine. Today, I did some changes to the website in my local machine. So I pushed the changes to GitHub and then cloned the GitHub repo again  to the server. Then, I installed the dependencies and restarted PM2.

Now, when I visit my site `https://sundaray.io`, I get the following error.
[image]

The following is the error log.
[image]

How can I fix the error?

Comment: looks like your node as not running properly with pm2 please check it

Comment: 502 gateway mean server and Nginx is getting your request but there is issue with upstream.

Comment: try running the node server with pm2 and check application getting crashed or other 500 error..

Comment: Same as last time. Please share `sudo nginx -T` output. From what I can see your configuration need some general cleanup.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I have to create a `.env` file. By the way, why can't I copy paste code from VS code to VIM? I tried `ctrl+v` and `ctrl+shift+v`, but doesn't work.

Comment: Everything ok now. The server is working fine.

Comment: Thanks Timo and Harsh for your prompt responses. You guys are the best.

Answer (score 0):

Simple meaning is

```
No HTTP server response, your Node Http server is not answering requests.
```

502 gateway mean server and Nginx is getting your request but there is issue with upstream.

you can use the command to show the logs of pm2

```
pm2 show
```

the application might be crashing or internal server 500 error.